# How do you convert a string to double?

Tags: c, pointers

How can I write a program that reads an input string and converts the string into a float number.

I'm a bit stuck for the function `double convert_to_double (char *)`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double convert_to_double (char *);

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    s = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);
    printf("The number is %lf", convert_to_double (str));
    return 0;
}

double convert_to_double (char *str)
{
    char *s;
    double result;
    result = strtod(str, &s);


    if (s != NULL)
    {
        char *anotherEnd;
        double anotherResult = strtod(s, &anotherEnd);
    }
    if (isalnum(s) == 0)
    {  
        printf("Wrong digit entered..");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you're not using `str` anywhere in the function. You're just calling `strtod(s, &ptr);` with two uninitialized variables

Comment: May I suggest using something like `scanf("%lf", &myDouble)`? With checking the return value?

Comment: @phuclv i've altered it, is this what you mean?

Comment: What is an example input with symbols and operators? What output you expect for this input?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strictly validate the input string, please try:

```
double convert_to_double(char *str)
{
    char *e;
    double d = strtod(str, &e);
    if (*e != '\n') {
        fprintf(stderr, "input error %c\n", *e);
        exit(1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

The character `*e` is the first character remaining after the valid number
representation is converted; usually a newline in this usage.
If you do not have to check the input string so strictly, just say:

```
double convert_to_double(char *str)
{
    double d = strtod(str, (char **)NULL);
    return d;
}
```

You may not have to functionize it.

Comment: If `str` was only `"\n"`, the first `convert_to_double()` would not detect that as an error.  The best test for _no conversion_ is `if (str == e) ...`, useful to add to the trailing junk text.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong way for strtod :

```
double convert_to_double (char *str) {
{
    char *s;
    double result;
    // first parameter is the string you want to convert
    // second pram is a pointer to the first char which was not converted.
    // this can be used if you have more than one data to convert in the same string
    result = strtod(str, &s);
    // example of using returned pointer :
    if (s != NULL) {
        char *anotherEnd;
        double anotherResult = strtod(s, &anotherEnd);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use strtod() function for this question? If yes, how do you do it? Like let's say using strlen() only or just some normal ways without any string functions...

Comment: @hamburgerwhoselflearns, everything is possible. You can analyze the input string char by char and do anything you want. Think at the string "12": it means 1*10+2. If the string was "123", 1*100+2*10+3. Does this suggest something to you? Start with result=0, then get char by char, multiply result by ten and add the new digit, and so on.

Comment: @hamburgerwhoselflearns what's wrong with `strtod`? This is _the_ function to use.

Comment: @hamburgerwhoselflearns : you also have atof function.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you convert a *string* to `double`?

`if (s != NULL)` is not a useful test.  The end pointer `s` is never `NULL` when attempting to convert a *string*.

Use `strtod()`.  Test for potential errors.

```
double convert_to_double (const char *str) {
  // Optional test of str, which suppose to point to a string
  if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Null pointer\n");
    return NAN;
  }

  char *endptr;  // Location of end of conversion.
  errno = 0;
  double result = strtod(str, &endptr);

  if (str == endptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No conversion of <%s>\n", str);
    return NAN;
  }

  // Consume trailing white-space. 
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Trailing junk <%s>\n", str);
    return result;
  }

  if (errno) {
    perror("Error:");
    return result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

Pedantically the last test should be more forgiving as *underflow* is usually not a real problem.

```
  if (errno) {
    if (errno != ERANGE && fabs(result > DBL_MIN)) { 
      perror("Error:");
      return result;
    }
  }
```

---

A `double` may be [hundreds of digits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) in text form.  Be generous in buffer size.

```
// s = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
#define DBL_STR_SIZE 2000
str = malloc(sizeof *str * DBL_STR_SIZE);
if (str) {
  printf("Enter text: ");
  if (fgets(str, DBL_STR_SIZE, stdin)) {
    // process str
```